# Why isn't the tail of the Moment vector at the tail of the position and force vector?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, vectors, torque

When I was first introduced to the concept of the vector product, e.g. V=PxQ, I always saw P and Q drawn on a plane with a common point of origin, and V drawn perpendicular to the plane formed by P and Q, with its tail at that same point of origin; so together the three vectors looked like the corner of a room.
However, when I was introduced to the concept of moment about a point, e.g. M = rxF, M's tail shared an origin point with r, but not the common point where r and F came together. So then I started to wonder how you know where the tail of the resulting vector of a vector product is located. Is Moment different somehow because r is a position vector rather than a force vector?

Comment: Maybe it's me but I get reather confused with the pysical meaning of your vectors. But in general a vector is always pointing from the origin to the designated point. However you may always move it around in your coordinate system for didiactic purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors inherently do not have any starting position. If you add two vectors together, you put the tail of the second to the head of the first. You are allowed to do that, because a vector is only something that has a direction and a distance, but no origin.

The graphical illustration of the vector product is just convenient. But the definition of the moment, $\vec M = \vec r \times \vec F$, just tells you what the direction and magnitude of the moment are. It does not tell you where the moment acts upon.

Comment: I've read that some vectors are 'free', some are 'sliding', and some are 'fixed'. Maybe that's what's confusing me.